# Can you integrate Cobertura into IntelliJ 12

Tags: intellij-idea, code-coverage, cobertura

We use Cobertura inside our maven builds, and I would like to use the Cobertura coverage engine for coverage inside IntelliJ 12 so that we have the same results.

I can't work out how, or if it's possible, to use Cobertura as the coverage tool for IntelliJ.

Answer (score 1):

A little late, but as far as I can tell it is **not** possible today. According to this [Comparison of code coverage tools](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/CLOVER/Comparison+of+code+coverage+tools) IntelliJ does not support Cobertura. Also in 2008 one of the IntelliJ [devs expressed interest](http://cobertura.996293.n3.nabble.com/Using-Cobertura-in-IntelliJ-IDEA-td1858.html) in supporting Cobertura -> suggesting that IntelliJ does not support Cobertura.

Also IntelliJ never mentions anything about Cobertura in their [code coverage documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.2/code-coverage.html)